# How to assign all NULL values in a column with the non-Null values based on a group?

Tags: sql

I have found a lot of help explaining how to replace NULL with 0 or with the previous value but I want to replace the Null values with the non-null values.

For each group in my data the registration number is either one integer or NULL and I want to replace all the NULL values with the non-null values.

So for this table I want to replace all the null values with 32550 for that group.

Comment: What is a "group"?  Do you somehow think that the ordering is important?

Comment: Hi, A group is for each column1, column2, column3, column4, column5. so there will be a new registration number for each of thoses groups of columns

Comment: Your question does not make sense without there being some other column besides `Registration` which provides an order to the data you are showing us.  Please show us the actual table.

Comment: what columns are those? You haven't shown us any other columns or data. Don't forget we can't see your screen and we know nothing about your schema...we can't make sense of what you're asking without seeing a proper example.

Comment: Poor sample data, add some other values too. And without any key, there's nothing to order by to get the previous value.

Comment: Is widerlocationcode can be consider as group value?

Comment: it's still unclear precisely how you define "group". We can see here that some of the rows have NULL in the registration column. How do we know which of those rows should be given registration ID 32543 and which should be given some other ID? I assume it's dependent on the value in one or more of the other columns? What value(s) would cause you to allocate a specific ID? P.S. A better data sample would include some rows with a different Registration, so that we can start to see the differences between the "groups".

Comment: For this example they should all be 32543.

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL offers both `lag()` and `last_value()` with the `ignore nulls` option.  Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can get the most recent row with a value using:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(registration,
                last_value(registration ignore nulls) over (order by <ordering column>)
               ) as imputed_registration
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table like this:

```
Group   | Registration
----------------------
A       | 32543
A       | 32543
A       | NULL
A       | 32543
B       | 12345
B       | 12345
B       | NULL
```

You could do something like this:

```
UPDATE my_table AS a
  SET registration = (
    SELECT max(registration)
      FROM my_table AS b
      WHERE b.group = a.group
  );
```

This works only if the "registration" is always the same for a given "group" and it will leave the "registration" as NULL if there are no records with NON-NULL "registration".